# pandas filtering using isin function

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframe as shown below
df1:

```
ID      Name
1       Sachin
2       Kholi
3       Dravid
```

df2:

```
ID      Run
1       20
2       60
2       10
1       5
```

From the above I want to filter df1 by only taking unique ids in df2:

Expected output:

```
ID      Name
3       Dravid
```

I tried below code

```
def diff(first, second):
        second = set(second)
        units_in_unit_table = [item for item in first if item not in second]
        return units_in_unit_table
id_df2 = diff(df2, df1)

df3 = df1[df1['ID'].isin(id_df2)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your solution should be simplify by pass unique values to `isin` by [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) with invert mask by `~`:

```
df3 = df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'].unique())]
```

Or by `set`:

```
df3 = df1[~df1['ID'].isin(set(df2['ID']))]
```

---

```
print (df3)
   ID    Name
2   3  Dravid
```