# Filter Dataframe by using ~isin([list_of_substrings])

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, substring

Given a dataframe full of emails, I want to filter out rows containing potentially blocked domain names or clearly fake emails. The dataframe below represents an example of my data.

```
>> print(df)

        email                number
1   fake@fake.com              2
2   real.email@gmail.com       1
3   no.email@email.com         5
4   real@yahoo.com             2  
5   rich@money.com             1
```

I want to filter by two lists. The first list is `fake_lst = ['noemail', 'noaddress', 'fake', ... 'no.email']`.
The second list is just the set `from disposable_email_domains import blocklist` converted to a list (or kept as a set).

When I use `df = df[~df['email'].str.contains('noemail')]` it works fine and filters out that entry. Yet when I do `df = df[~df['email'].str.contains(fake_lst)]` I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

The obvious answer is to use `df = df[~df['email'].isin(fake_lst)]` as in many other stackoverflow questions, like [Filter Pandas Dataframe based on List of substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785687/filter-pandas-dataframe-based-on-list-of-substrings) or [pandas filtering using isin function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183227/pandas-filtering-using-isin-function) but that ends up having no effect.

I suppose I could use `str.contains('string')` for each possible list entry, but that is ridiculously cumbersome.

Therefore, I need to filter this dataframe based on the substrings contained in the two lists such that any email containing a particular substring I want rid of, and the subsequent row in which it is contained, are removed.

In the example above, the dataframe after filtering would be:

```
>> print(df)

        email                number
2   real.email@gmail.com       1
4   real@yahoo.com             2  
5   rich@money.com             1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas filtering for multiple substrings in series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541444/pandas-filtering-for-multiple-substrings-in-series)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution assuming you have following `df` and `fake_lst`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'email': ['fake@fake.com', 'real.email@gmail.com', 'no.email@email.com',
              'real@yahoo.com', 'rich@money.com'],
    'number': [2, 1, 5, 2, 1]
})

fake_lst = ['fake', 'money']
```

**Option 1:**

Filter out rows that have any of the `fake_lst` words in email with `apply`:

```
df.loc[
    ~df['email'].apply(lambda x: any([i in x for i in fake_lst]))
]
```

```
                  email  number
1  real.email@gmail.com       1
2    no.email@email.com       5
3        real@yahoo.com       2
```

**Option 2:**

Filter out without `apply`

```
df.loc[
    [not any(i) for i in zip(*[df['email'].str.contains(word) for word in fake_lst])]
]
```

```
                  email  number
1  real.email@gmail.com       1
2    no.email@email.com       5
3        real@yahoo.com       2
```

Comment: This works well, but I am trying to avoid using  `apply`, as on a large df it takes forever.

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch I added another option, this time without using `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin) to check whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values. Another issue is that your fake list contains the name without the domain so you need str.split to remove the characters you are not matching against.

Note: str.contains tests if a pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series and hence your code df['email'].str.contains('noemail') works fine but doesn't work for list

```
df[~df['email'].str.split('@').str[0].isin(fake_lst)]


    email                   number
0   fake@fake.com           2
1   real.email@gmail.com    1
3   real@yahoo.com          2
4   rich@money.com          1
```

Comment: It may work in practice, but that wasn't the question.
You assume that the fake name always appear before the `@`, and no one said that this has to be the case.

Comment: `pat = '|'.join(fake_lst); df[~df.email.str.contains(pat)]`